# get last name and phone number from appScript and google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, whatsapp

I have these two functions that take data from a google sheet and then send a whatsapp message. I can't modify the first function (getSheetData_) to take only the data from the last row. I only have two columns (name and phone). I have a trigger that launches the script on every change.

source: https://www.labnol.org/whatsapp-api-google-sheets-220520

```
const getSheetData_ = () => {
  const [header, ...rows] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const data = [];
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const recipient = { };
    header.forEach((title, column) => {
      recipient[title] = row[column];
    });
    data.push(recipient);
  });
  return data;
};

const main = () => {
  const data = getSheetData_();
    data.forEach((recipient) => {
      const status = sendMessage_({
        recipient_number: recipient["Phone Number"].replace(/[^\d]/g, ""),
        customer_name: recipient["Customer Name"]
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: It looks like you copied this code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: source added to post

Comment: Try `const [header, ...rows] = (sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()).getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,2).getDisplayValues();`

Comment: @TheMaster thank you i'm getting the last row but data.push(recipient); not works. my array is empty

Comment: @TheMaster rows is undefined

Comment: Add a header separately  like: `const header = ['Phone Number','Customer Name']` and the first statement like: `const rows = ...`(instead of `const [header, ...rows]=...`)

Comment: @TheMaster ok i found the solution now it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
const getSheetData_ = () => {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,2);
  const header = ['Customer Name', 'Phone Number'];
  const rows = lastRow.getDisplayValues();
  const data = [];
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const recipient = { };
    header.forEach((title, column) => {
      recipient[title] = row[column];
    });
    data.push(recipient);
  });
  return data;
};
```